# How to add a pager to the page with php?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I'd like to add a pagination function to the page.

I have this piece of code:

```
$result = mysql_query( "select title from post LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->title;
}
```

I'd like to show only five post titles per page. If I want to add a pager to this page, how do I  do this? E.g: the URL is `example.com/post.html`.

Comment: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parameter in the query string that indicates the page that you are looking.

So for example: example.com/post.html?page=2 means that someone clicked on the link to the second page.

And then in your code you can do something like this:

```
$rowsPerPage = 5;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '0';
$index = $page * $rowsPerPage;
$result = mysql_query( 'select title from post LIMIT ' . $index . ', ' . $rowsPerPage);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   echo $row->title;
}
```

Also you need get the total quantity of records that you have in order to print the pagination links. You can use a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POST to get the total of rows. Then you have to calculate how many pages you will show.

Hope this helps you

Comment: if the  total quantity of records is $total, how do i do?

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to make the offset dynamic, so the first page is 0, the second 5, the third 10, etc. 
you can use a GET protocol to send the offset to the URL with each pagination:

```
<a href="example.com/post.html?offset=0">1</a>
<a href="example.com/post.html?offset=5">2</a>
<a href="example.com/post.html?offset=10">3</a>
```

obviously you generate the pagination links dynamically with a for loop, the formula being (OFFSET= (num_pag-1) * LIMIT)

then you PHP would be:

```
$offset = $_GET['offset'];
$result = mysql_query( "select title from post LIMIT 5 OFFSET $offset");
```

Comment: OFFSET= (num_pag-1) * LIMIT what's these meaning. thank you. if the total rows = $total.